# Save texture buffer as text file

Tags: c++, qt

i'm reversing a tool that take as input a file and visualize file bytes distribution in 2D/3D. i wanna save the data represented in 3D as text for external analysis. is it possible? the following is the code that initialize the texture that is used. I've tried to save "data", but does not contains anything usefull, so the idea is to save the texture buffer, that, in this code, should "databuff"

```
void TrigramWidget::initTextures() {
  auto size = static_cast<int>(getDataSize());
  auto* data = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(getData());
  //------------TEST-----------
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/home/isfet/outputs/data_buff_trigram.txt", "w");
  fprintf(fp, "%d, %x\n", size,getData());
  fclose(fp);

  databuf_ = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::Type(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER));
  databuf_->create();
  databuf_->bind();
  databuf_->allocate(data, size);
  databuf_->release();

  texture_ = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::TargetBuffer);
  texture_->setSize(size);
  texture_->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::R8U);
  texture_->create();
  texture_->bind();
  //------------TEST-----------
  /*QFile file("/home/isfet/outputs/texture_buffer.txt");
  file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  file.write(databuf_);
  file.close();*/
  glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, QOpenGLTexture::R8U, databuf_->bufferId());
}
```

Comment: You write some text-data to the file, the you close it. You never write the actual texture itself. And in the `file.write(databuf_)` call you're using [this `write` overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#write-1), which is for writing a null-terminated string. Not a `QOpenGLBuffer` object. You need to get the texture itself, and find out some useful text-based format for it, and then convert the binary data to text that can be written in the defined format.

Comment: Oh, and reopening the file with `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)` will *truncate* the existing contents of the file, so it's lost.